# CCMoveto not moving

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Im starting with CoCos2d development and I think I have some issues with nodespace, and actions, this is my code and nothings moving although I seem to have no errors when running the code, any comments are appreciated:

```
    +(id) create {
    return [[self alloc] init];}

    -(id) init {
        if ((self = [super init]))
        {
        CGSize scSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    self.position = ccp(0,scSize.height);;


    touchArea = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"touchArea.png"]; 
    [touchArea setAnchorPoint:ccp(0, 0.5)];
    [self addChild:touchArea];


    obj_1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"obj1.png"];
    obj_2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"obj2.png"];
    obj_3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"obj3.png"];

    obj_tab = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, nil];


        for (int i=0; i < obj_tab.count; i++)
        {
            CCSprite *obj = [obj_tab objectAtIndex:i];
            float offSetPos = ((float)(i+1)) / (obj_tab.count +1);
            CGPoint pos = ccp(scSize.width*offSetPos, 0);
            obj.position = pos;
            [obj setAnchorPoint:ccp(0.5, -0.25)];
            [touchArea addChild:obj];
        }

    velocidad = 3;
    destino = ccp(0,-100);
    //[self scheduleUpdate];
    [self moveIt] // <-- Edited to call another method
 }   
    return self;

}

-(void) moveit{
    CCMoveTo *moverAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5 position:ccp(0,0)];
    CCCallFunc *onEndAction = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(onEndMove:)];
    CCSequence *moveSequence = [CCSequence actions: moverAction, onEndAction, nil];
    [touchArea runAction:moveSequence];
{

-(void) update:(ccTime)delta {

}

-(void)onEndMove:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"OnEndMove fired");
}

-(void) onEnter{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-1 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

-(void) onExit {
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
}


-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGRect boundingBox = touchArea.boundingBox;
    boundingBox.origin = CGPointZero;

    BOOL isTouchHandled = CGRectContainsPoint(boundingBox, [touchArea convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch]);

    //NSLog(@"touchLocation y = %f", touchLocation.y);
    //NSLog(@"touchArea y = %f", touchArea.position.y);

    if (isTouchHandled){
        NSLog(@"Touch Handled");
    }

    return isTouchHandled;

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that 'self' , the class of the code showed above, derives from CCNode. Make certain that 'self' is running, it must be a descendant of CCNode, and will be running when it is added to a running node.  This is what happens in a CCNode's onEnter (taken from version 1.0.1):

```
-(void) onEnter
{
    [children_ makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(onEnter)];  
    [self resumeSchedulerAndActions];

    isRunning_ = YES;
}
```

this is where the scheduler and actions are enabled for the node. If it is never invoked, your actions will not run.

You could move your moveIt code to the onEnter method, which will be invoked when the object becomes running.

```
-(void) onEnter{
    CCLOG(@"%@<onEnter> : invoked",self.class);
    [self moveIt];
    [super onEnter];   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yves, I just called [super onEnter] (my custom class inherited from CCNODE), and now it's working, I am following a book "Learn CoCos2D game dev..." and in the code provided there's not even a call to the onEnter for the custom class derived from CCNODE an yet it manages to perform the actions... I don't understand yet it works, a bittersweet win ^^. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the resource you are using is a very good one. Get familiar with coco's internal, dont be afraid to look in the code to figure out what is really happening 'under the hood' and you will soon be up to speed. It is a great framework to work with, once you get its object model and how to make it work for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How frequently is `-(void) update:(ccTime)delta` being called? (Probably started in your `scheduleUpdate` method.)  Chances are you're calling that `[touchArea runAction:moveSequence];` several times per second, which queues up tons of those CCMoveTos.

You should probably move your `runAction:`s out of there entirely, or at least add some logic to your `update:` method to check whether `touchArea` should be kicking off another `runAction:`.

Comment: Thanks I see that point however I changed the scheduleUpdate (I've just edited the code in the original message) and still no motion :(

Comment: @Rubs You're telling it to move touchArea to position 0,0... that's the default position.  Try putting in something like: `ccp(150,150)`

Comment: Hi HachiEthan, I played around with some different values for the moverAction position, for example to ccp(0,-240), my intention is to move it top down in portrait mode, but still nothing moves. The original position self.position = ccp(0,scSize.height); is for the whole node, I also tried to move it instead of [touchArea runAction...], originally I set [self run action:moveSequence]... thanks for your kind answers and time!